# Is it necessary to keep changing the constant when solving a separable differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

When solving a separable differential equation, do you keep changing the constant to $C_1$, $C_2$ and so on or do you leave $C$ until the end (since they're just arbitrary constants)?

**Possibility $1$**

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 6y^2 x\\
\frac{dy}{6y^2} &= x \ dx\\
\int \frac{dy}{6y^2} &= \int x \ dx\\
- \frac{1}{6y} &= \frac{x^2}{2} + C\\
- \frac{1}{y} &= 3x^2 + C_1\\
\frac{1}{y} &= -3x^2 + C_2\\
y &= \frac{1}{-3x^2+C_2}
\end{align}

**Possibility $2$**

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 6y^2 x\\
\frac{dy}{6y^2} &= x \ dx\\
\int \frac{dy}{6y^2} &= \int x \ dx\\
- \frac{1}{6y} &= \frac{x^2}{2} + C\\
- \frac{1}{y} &= 3x^2 + C\\
\frac{1}{y} &= -3x^2 + C\\
y &= \frac{1}{-3x^2+C}
\end{align}

Comment: Both are incorrect. Look at the last step.

Comment: @Hellen thank you I closed the {} tag sooner than I should.

Comment: Most teachers teaching high school calculus will insist that you change the constant everytime, but its not necessary. Though you want to keep track of the range of values the constant can take..

Comment: It is not 3x^2  but x^2/12.

Comment: Since the derivative of a constant is zero, any constant will work.  Just use C.  You're not really worried about particular choices of C here...

Comment: If you're worried about it, write something like "where each $C$ is an arbitrary constant, in general different from one line to the next."  Hmm, I may have caught something from my son the lawyer.